# How add timestamp to downloaded filename from curl in bash script?

Tags: bash, curl

I am working on a `bash` script and `curl` to download file from a server. I am trying to add `date` in format `$(date +"%y-%m-%d")` to the file that will be downloaded. Below is my curl call

```
curl --fail -S -O -C - --location "${HEADERS[@]}" -X GET "$url"
```

With above call the file is downloading fine (example filename: test.txt). Now I want to add date to the file. I think if we use `-o` option then we can add it like `curl -o test-$(date +"%y-%m-%d").txt` but in my case I want to store the filename as it is from remote file name. Is it possible to do the same with `-O` option?
Also if we add the date to remote file name will it affect the `-C -` option? Can we still have the resuming interrupted downloads feature?

Expected output:
Filename after downloading: test-YYYY-MM-DD.txt

P.S: Please let em know if any info is missing. I am working on `Ubuntu` and the script will be part of `BusyBox` system. Also, sorry if the question is more of a discussion.

Comment: Better add a concrete example with URL and expected output

Comment: @GillesQuénot, I have updated OP. Hope it's more clear now

Comment: Since you already know how to calculate the timestamp: To change the name of a file, use the command `mv`. See _man mv_.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
file=subscriptionList.opml 
curl -o "${file%.*}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).${file#*.}" -s "$url" -C -
ls
```

```
subscriptionList_2023-05-11.opml
```

Comment: You can use `-o, --output <file>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$ url="https://example.com/media/document.txt"
$ curl -o "$(basename ${url%.*}-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").${url##*.})" -s "$url" -C -
```

Whether or not the transfer can be resumed depends on if the server supports byte ranges (you can check by omitting `-s`).

Comment: Hello, what happens if there is dot (.) in the remote file name (e.x, test.tmp.txt). where will the date gets added?

Comment: @Preeti The date will get added before the extension (eg. `test.tmp-2023-05-11.txt`).